# how to fill color of IconButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I use an `IconButton` to show the status of user collection status, this is my code snippet:

```
 if (item.isFav == 1)
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Feather.bookmark,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav"),
    ),
```

but the icon just change the icon lines color like this:

[image]

Is it possible to fill the color with yellow of this icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is changing only the color of the border is that the icon you have used doesn't have fill color. If you want to fill the color of the entire icon then you should use a different icon. Try the following code:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, 
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
  onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav"),
),
```

[Official Bookmark Icon document link:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/bookmark-constant.html)