# How do I change bookmark_outline to bookmark onPressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's what I have...

```
IconButton(icon: Icon (Icons.bookmark_outline, color: Color(0xFF192A4F),),
                                      onPressed: () => Icons.bookmark, color: Color(0xFF192A4F),),
```

I don't know what I'm doing. All I've been able to find is this

[how to fill color of IconButton in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274452/how-to-fill-color-of-iconbutton-in-flutter?fbclid=IwAR1EjoWMhU4sIKAYXuljx0L9Iv5oYDA5bmTCrHV-dJB_izZG_jbni0czfLQ)

but I couldn't get that to work.

I just want the icon to change when tapped... I'm new.

What worked:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool outline = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
```

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[

      IconButton(icon: Icon(outline ? Icons.bookmark_outline : Icons.bookmark),
          onPressed:(){
            setState((){
              outline = !outline;
            });
          }
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 8.0),
      Text('Bookmark', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF192A4F)),),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need do like this,

create a boolean variable,

`bool outline = false;`

now in the on press function,

```
onPressed:(){
setState(){
  outline = !outline;
}
}
```

now for the your Icon do something like this,

```
icon: Icon(outline ? Icons.bookmark_outline : Icons.bookmark):
```

**Make sure your are using stateful widget**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it's not working for me... it's stuck on Icons.bookmark. It only changes to Icons.bookmark_outline if I change bool outline to true... I don't understand

Comment: @Leena Marie Can you update the question with the code

Comment: @LeenaMarie add the boolean variable inside the state class, like this `class _HomeState extends State<Home> {bool outline = false; @override ...}`

Comment: It's still not working... I updated my code

Comment: @LeenaMarie Hey! there might be something that you are doing wrong so try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125284/13109948 it has same functionality as your it toggles password's visibility so this might help

Comment: Thank you! It's changing now :) I missed a bracket...